# The residual gauge symmetry of Yang-Mills theory after Wick rotation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, yang-mills, gauge

I am a bit puzzled by a statement in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/554955/eliminating-residual-gauge-in-brst-quantization-of-yang-mills-theory) question here. In particular, the claim that the residual gauge symmetry in Yang-Mills theory disappears upon Wick rotation to the Euclidean theory.

For concreteness, lets consider a gauge group $U(1)$, so our action is simply
$$
S=-\frac{1}{4}\int d^{4}x F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}
$$
Where $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}$ is the field strength tensor, and for now we are in Minkowski space with signature $(-1,+1,+1,+1)$.

It is clear that this action has a gauge symmetry, $A_{\mu}\to A_{\mu}':=A_{\mu}+\partial_{\mu}\Lambda$, for an arbitrary scalar function $\Lambda$. Furthermore, by choosing $\Lambda$ such that $\Box\Lambda=-\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu}$, we find that we can set $\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu}'=0$, this is called the Lorenz gauge.

There is a residual gauge freedom given  by choosing $\Lambda'$ such that $\Box\Lambda'=0$, since under this gauge transformation $\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu}'\mapsto \partial^{\mu}A_{\mu}'':=\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu}'+\Box\Lambda'=0$. So to fully fix the gauge, we also have to choose a function satisfying $\Box\Lambda'=(-\partial_{t}^{2}+\partial_{x}^{2}+\partial_{y}^{2}+\partial_{z}^{2})\Lambda'=0$.

The claim is that after a Wick rotation to Euclidean theory, this residual gauge freedom disappears. Definging $t=-i\tau$, the Wick rotated action is:
$$
S^{E}=\frac{1}{4}\int d^{4}xF_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}
$$
where the signature is now $(+1,+1,+1,+1)$.

This action again has a gauge symmetry $A_{\mu}\to A_{\mu}+\partial_{\mu}\Lambda$, and we can again choose Lorenz gauge by picking a $\Lambda$ such that $\Box\Lambda=-\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu}$, where now $\Box=\partial^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}=\nabla^{2}$, the Laplacian.

It appears to me that we once again have residual gauge freedom. Namely, that we can transform by a function $\Lambda$ such that $\nabla^{2}\Lambda=0$, so it really seems like the residual gauge symmetry has not disappeared in the Wick rotated theory!

My guess is that I am either misinterpreting what it means for the residual gauge freedom to disappear, or that I am missing an issue with the existence of solutions to the equations defining $\Lambda$ in Euclidean space. I would really appreciate some help resolving this issue.

Answer (score 3):

In chapter 74 of [Srednicki's QFT book](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html) (which the [previous Phys.SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/554955/2451) refers to) it is implicitly assumed that in Euclidean 4D $x$-space the gauge field $A_{\mu}$ vanishes sufficiently fast as $|x|\to \infty$. In particular, [large gauge transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_gauge_transformation) are implicitly excluded. In this case, the only [harmonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function) $\Lambda$ (i.e. such that $\Box\Lambda=0$) is the zero-function $\Lambda\equiv 0$, cf. the [maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Maximum_principle), so that the gauge is completely fixed.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is definitely starting to clear things up. However, since (in Lorenz gauge), we have the equation of motion $\Box A_{\mu}=0$ for the gauge fields, would this not also imply that the $A_{\mu}$ themselves are rapidly decaying harmonic functions and thus zero?